# angular puts all my input fields on the same row

Tags: angular

I have a component made of a form with a few fields. When my component is rendered all the fields are on the same line like showed in the picture below. I do not want to introduce `<br>` between the fields because in that case the fields are not aligned which produces an ugly result. Here is the component code:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input formControlName="firstName" id="firstName" />

    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input formControlName="lastName" id="lastName" />

    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input formControlName="address" type="address" id="address" />    
    
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input formControlName="email" type="email" id="email" />    

    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input formControlName="phone" type="phone" id="phone" />    

    <label for="fare">Fare:</label>
    <select class="form-select" formControlName="fare" (change)="onSelectFare()">
        <option [value]="fare.name" *ngFor="let fare of availableFares">{{fare.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and its corresponding css:

```
:host {
    border: 2px solid #1725e6;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
```

Would you know what is wrong with my code ?

[image]

Comment: it's not an angular problem. you need some styling library or do it yourself in CSS. using a flex layout could be a good option.

Comment: hii @eurydice use bootstrap more easy and responsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not angular problem, it's about CSS properties position

It could achieve by adding css property `display: block` to the tag

```
label {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you need, but if you want the inputs to be one below the other, then try this:

```
<div class="row" >
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input  id="firstName" />
</div>
    <div class="row mt-2">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input  id="lastName" />

</div>
```

Where mt stand for margin-top. Maybe like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaQTG.png)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to used some Styling and responsive frameworks like bootstrap.

You can Include bootstrap in your project with three ways

## First way

with CDN (Content Delivery Network)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
```

## Second Way

with NPM package

```
npm i bootstrap
```

## Third Way

with some CSS Properties like

```
display: block;
```

you can check bootstrap document [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/)